# Stop duplicated indexing

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to stop duplicate entry's into my database (below). eg it will come up with an error message if the vechID, Collection date, and return date is the same. I am opening my table in design view and clicking indexes and then indexing the relevant fields.  but it wont work let me and keeps saying no due to duplicate values. is this the correct method

```
Booking ID  VechID  CuID    Collection date      Return date
1              3    7       01/07/2017           10/07/2018
2              1    7       23/04/2017           16/05/2018
3              2    1       17/05/2017           28/05/2018
4              4    2       15/05/2017           20/05/2018
5              5    2       01/06/2017           24/06/2018
6              6    2       22/07/2017           29/08/2018
7              4    8       01/07/2017           15/07/2018
8              8    8       01/08/2017           20/08/2018
9              8    2       21/01/2017           20/01/2018
10             4    8       25/09/2017           02/10/2018
13             8    8       25/09/2017           02/10/2018
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to create a **unique** index on the fields (vechID, Collection date, return date).

Of course you can't do that if you already have data in your table that violates this unique index.

Use the query wizard for Duplicate Search to find and delete them.